# Нужны исходники маленьких программ на C или C/GTK

Tags: c, gtk, opensource

В учебных целях. Написанные в хорошем стиле и с комментариями. Хотелось бы не лабораторные работы, а реальные действующие программы, которыми кто-то пользуется.

C++ не предлагать.

Comment: hddparm. Утилита для работы с жесткими дисками. Брать с sourceforce.
Еще могу оттуда же порекомендовать стянуть smartmontools

Answer (score 3):

[Командные утилиты проекта OpenBSD](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/bin/).

BSD'шный код считается примером качественного кода, написанного на Си.

Что касается C/GTK, то тут возможно вам пригодятся [gnome-games](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-games/tree/).

Answer (score 2):

XChat клиент чата IRC.
Протокола там не много, поэтому почти весь код - это интерфейс приложения.

[исходники](http://xchat.org/files/source/2.8/xchat-2.8.8.tar.xz)